# Does python have something like php java bridge?

Tags: java, python

Does python have something like [php java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)? I've found only py4j, but I couldn't find implementation of python + tomcat.

Could you recomend something?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Jython](http://www.jython.org/). It lets you run Python on the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

From the php-java-bridge site:

> The PHP/Java Bridge is an implementation of a streaming, XML-based network protocol, which can be used to connect a native script engine, for example PHP, Scheme or **Python**, with a Java virtual machine.

Example:
http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/examples/source.php?source=getProperties.py

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/). But it seems there is no active development on that project, of late.

Comment: If you have control over your dev stack, jython makes a great 'replacement' for the defunct jpype. (As mentioned above by Daniel Hepper)